# UdpClient could not be found

Tags: c#

I am a newby programming in c# and have the following question. I want to make a program which receives Udp broadcast. In my program I want use UdpClient but got the message that the namespace could not be found. I have included System.Net.Sockets in my program. Could anybody help me to solve this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace Console
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides application-specific behavior to supplement the default Application class.
    /// </summary>
    sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
        /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
        /// </summary>
        UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(11000);
        public App()
        {
            Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync(
                Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.Metadata |
                Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.Session);
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when the application is launched normally by the end user.  Other entry points
        /// will be used such as when the application is launched to open a specific file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the launch request and process.</param>
        protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {

#if DEBUG
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
            }
#endif

            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
            // just ensure that the window is active
            if (rootFrame == null)
            {
                // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
                rootFrame = new Frame();

                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

                if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
                {
                    //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
                }

                // Place the frame in the current Window
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            }

            if (rootFrame.Content == null)
            {
                // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
                // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
                // parameter
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
            }
            // Ensure the current window is active
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when Navigation to a certain page fails
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The Frame which failed navigation</param>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the navigation failure</param>
        void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to load Page " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when application execution is being suspended.  Application state is saved
        /// without knowing whether the application will be terminated or resumed with the contents
        /// of memory still intact.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the suspend request.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the suspend request.</param>
        private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
        {
            var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
            //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
            deferral.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code here, along with the includes?

Answer (score 0):

Good Afternoon Wamor:
I just created a class in my WPF Project and it compiled just fine:
What type of project are you working on? This is Visual Studio 2013 Targeting .Net Framework 4.5

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HalliburtonCallouts.ViewModel
{
    public  class UPPClass
    {
        public UPPClass()
        {
            // This constructor arbitrarily assigns the local port number.
            UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(11000);
            try
            {
                udpClient.Connect("www.contoso.com", 11000);

                // Sends a message to the host to which you have connected.
                Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Is anybody there?");

                udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);

                // Sends a message to a different host using optional hostname and port parameters.
                UdpClient udpClientB = new UdpClient();
                udpClientB.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length, "AlternateHostMachineName", 11000);

                //IPEndPoint object will allow us to read datagrams sent from any source.
                IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

                // Blocks until a message returns on this socket from a remote host.
                Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
                string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

                // Uses the IPEndPoint object to determine which of these two hosts responded.
                Console.WriteLine("This is the message you received " +
                                             returnData.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("This message was sent from " +
                                            RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString() +
                                            " on their port number " +
                                            RemoteIpEndPoint.Port.ToString());

                udpClient.Close();
                udpClientB.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Mark and manabreak, thanks for having a look at my question. Please find my code below:

Comment: I having troubles to add code. Stupid question but how do I highlight my code?

Comment: I created a sample c# project and added system.net and system.net.sockets. I then want to enter  UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(11000);

Comment: Just managed to add my code. Just created a sample project and added system.net and system.net.sockets to my code. Then added line         UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(11000);

Answer (score 0):

Hello Wamor: Your Code ahad alot of usings and things that my system was struggling to find: I think that this answer can help you I just compiled your code while commenting the other items out with four comment chars '////' The point is the UDPClient was found:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
////using System.Windows.ApplicationModel;
////using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
////using Windows.Foundation;
////using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
////using Windows.UI.Xaml;
////using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
////using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
////using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
////using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
////using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
////using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace Console
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides application-specific behavior to supplement the default Application class.
    /// </summary>
    sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
        /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
        /// </summary>
        UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(11000);
        public App()
        {
            ////Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync(
            ////    Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.Metadata |
            ////    Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.Session);
            ////this.InitializeComponent();
            ////this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when the application is launched normally by the end user.  Other entry points
        /// will be used such as when the application is launched to open a specific file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the launch request and process.</param>
////        protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
////        {

////#if DEBUG
////            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
////            {
////                this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
////            }
////#endif

////            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

////            // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
////            // just ensure that the window is active
////            if (rootFrame == null)
////            {
////                // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
////                rootFrame = new Frame();

////                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

////                if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
////                {
////                    //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
////                }

////                // Place the frame in the current Window
////                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
////            }

////            if (rootFrame.Content == null)
////            {
////                // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
////                // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
////                // parameter
////                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
////            }
////            // Ensure the current window is active
////            Window.Current.Activate();
////        }

////        /// <summary>
////        /// Invoked when Navigation to a certain page fails
////        /// </summary>
////        /// <param name="sender">The Frame which failed navigation</param>
////        /// <param name="e">Details about the navigation failure</param>
////        void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
////        {
////            throw new Exception("Failed to load Page " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
////        }

////        /// <summary>
////        /// Invoked when application execution is being suspended.  Application state is saved
////        /// without knowing whether the application will be terminated or resumed with the contents
////        /// of memory still intact.
////        /// </summary>
////        /// <param name="sender">The source of the suspend request.</param>
////        /// <param name="e">Details about the suspend request.</param>
////        private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
////        {
////            var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
////            //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
////            deferral.Complete();
////        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forget to answer. I am using Visual Studio 2015. Maybe this makes a difference. I copied your code into my Visual Studio but still UdpClient is not available. Thanks for helping me so far.

Comment: Wamor: You are welcome. I think you will have to wait for someone with 2015 to aid you - Good luck

Comment: Hello Mark, just installed VS 2013 Express but having the same problems. Any idea what could be wrong here?